# ERROR TS2322: Type '~lib/array/Array<~lib/string/String> | null' is not assignable to type '~lib/array/Array<~lib/string/String>'

Tags: typescript, assemblyscript

Holder has an array of strings (holder.positions). And all this function wants to do is push the ID of the position parameter onto the array.

Here is my function

```
function updateHolder(holder: Holder, position: Position): void {
    if(holder.positions == null){
        const positions: string[] = [];
        holder.positions = positions;
    }
    holder.positions.push(position.id);
}
```

The error that I get is

```
ERROR TS2322: Type '~lib/array/Array<~lib/string/String> | null' is not assignable to type '~lib/array/Array<~lib/string/String>'.


holder.positions.push(position.id);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which seems to be saying "the thing you're trying to push onto the array is either a string array or null, but it has to be a string array". Which makes...no sense to me.

Comment: It really makes all sense. Imagine an array of string `const arr: string[] = []`, and after fetching an api, you either get a user object with a property .username that is either a string or null. if you want to add that username to the array you have to make sure it's a string first, for example using using `if(typeof(obj.username) === "string") arr.push(obj.username)`, this way it will add to the array only if it's a string.

Comment: @MalikLahlou I had a similar thought. But when I add
if(position.id==null){return;}
before my push, I still get the same error

Comment: Same with that more explicit type check that you suggested

Comment: Hmmm, try adding an excalamation point after `position.id`, it's to tell typescript that this is absolutely not null in no case `.push(position.id!)``

Comment: That still gets me the same error, plus a "INFO AS210: Expression is never 'null'.", which feels like typescript is mocking me

Comment: bruh at first it tells you that it can null and not that it will never be null im out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssemblyScript has stricter null safety during deducing non-nullability than TS for now.

So in AS you can fix by using exclamation `!`:

```
export function updateHolder(holder: Holder, position: Position): void {
    if (holder.positions == null) {
        holder.positions = [];
    }
    holder.positions!.push(position.id); // add "!"
}
```

Btw Dart also can't prove such cases:
https://dartpad.dev/df0be72a941f4d515a5ecfec6a8ee7d9

Due to this, in complex cases may be unsound. TypeScript ok with this because TS has already unsoundness in many cases.